# Javascript show element, hide element on page load. But it reverts

Tags: javascript, jquery

On page load I want to hide element `#buttonSaveArea`, show element `#buttonSaveShower`. Upon a click on `#buttonSaveShower`, it should hide, and `#buttonSaveArea` should appear.

The problem is, `$(document).ready` is called again and again. How to get around it? Also, when JavaScript is disabled, I would like just `#buttonSaveArea` to be visible right from the start.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#buttonSaveArea").hide();

  $("#buttonSaveShower").click(function(){
    $("#buttonSaveArea").fadeIn();
    $("#buttonSaveShower").hide();
  });
});


<!------ The element that should show the button below ---------------->
<div class="button" id="buttonSaveShower" style="clear:both; margin-top:15px;">
    <a href="" style="width:50px !important;"> edytuj </a>
</div>

<!------ Button: save ---------------->
<div class="fbCenter" id="buttonSaveArea">
    <input type="submit" value="Zapisz" class="formButton"
       onmouseover="this.className+=' pressed'"
       onmouseout="this.className=this.className.replace(' pressed', '')"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Are you clicking a link, or submitting a form? Sounds like you're just refreshing the page.

Comment: #buttonSaveArea is a div that contains a submit button, which is not yet pressed. #buttonSaveShower is a div with an empty link (just to make it appear as a link).

Comment: did you do <a href="#">?  Or is it reloading the page you are on?

Comment: I added the html as well. That's all I know. :)

Comment: Yep, replacing <a href=""> with <a href="#">  helped... Thanks Dave. Write proper answer so that I can accept it.  Me = html noob I guess. Thanks am not i am, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `<a href="">` with `<a href="#">` helped. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You should stop the anchor tag from reloading the page by using `event.preventDefault()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#buttonSaveArea").hide();

  $("#buttonSaveShower").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#buttonSaveArea").fadeIn();
    $("#buttonSaveShower").hide();
  });
});
```

Also, if you want to load the page with `#buttonSaveArea` as hidden. You should use css to hide it by default

```
#buttonSaveArea{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `event.preventDefault();` is interesting indeed. In Chrome it works well. However, in Firefox, it prevents the whole thing to work (appearing/disappearing stuff). "Also, when JavaScript is disabled, I would like just `#buttonSaveArea` to be visible right from the start."

Comment: @Yar make sure that there is an argument named event in your click event handler. Also, if you wan't to cater for the state where javaScript is disabled, you should go with the '$("#buttonSaveArea").hide();' in your document ready function and forget the CSS I posted.